# Why am I not getting CM12s OTA for the OnePlus One?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

I am not getting CM12s OTA for the OnePlus One. Although I hit system update a bunch of times.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version are you currently running? Also, [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/mirrors-for-official-cyanogen-roms-ota-updates.141825/) are all the updates that you can flash from Recovery or fastboot, including the OTA ones.

Comment: Could you  post an answer then, so as to help out others who may have the same issue in future?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason OTA updates for CM12 from 11 have not been working. So manually go into the recovery and install. After you have CM12 you will get OTA updates.